# Decode Image from Base64

Tags: import, string-manipulation, image

From a web API, I have a bunch of realllyyy long strings that look like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,(...)
```

Sites like this will decode these strings no problem, but Mathematica doesn't seem to be able to. `BaseDecode` gives me a ByteArray which can't be re-imported as a JPEG, and ImportString doesn't want to import as a JPEG either.

Is there any way, in Mathematica, to convert from a base64 encoded image to the image itself?

For experimentation, [here](https://pastebin.com/KHE6A3gR) is a dump of one of the image strings. It should end up looking like a semi-messed up cathedral thingy (I'm training GANs)

Answer (score 10):

You just got to remove the initial `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, everything after that is base64 encoded pixel data.

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/KHE6A3gR", "Text"];
data = StringReplace[data, "data:image/jpeg;base64," -> ""];
ImportString[data, "Base64"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh nice! I assumed it would need that to infer the type. Thank you!